# Python skips for loop iterations randomly

Tags: python

I am a relative novice when writing Python code. Here is my issue, I am restarting a server and need to verify services are restarted. Once the server has come back online I run a command and store the output to a txt. I then Start a for loop against the txt doc ensuring the service is started. However the for loop is skipped over sometimes and not others.

```
def verify_serv():
    print ("start verif placeholder")#for troubleshooting 

    txtdoc = open('output2.txt','r')
    regexp = re.compile(r'\[STARTING\]')
    regexp2 = re.compile(r'\[STARTED\]')

    for line in txtdoc:
        match = regexp.match(line)
        nomatch = regexp2.match(line)
        print('in for loop')#for troubleshooting 
        if match:
            print ('in if loop')#for troubleshooting 
            print ('Still Starting \n\n\n\n\n\n')# testing only
            time.sleep(5)
            break
        elif nomatch:
            print('Done')
            end_email()


    txtdoc.close()     
    os.remove('output2.txt')

    print('end loop')#for troubleshooting 
    match = None
    nomatch = None
    txtdoc = None
    time.sleep(60)
    command_2()# pull new output file to recheck
```

I will also add some output.

```
admin:#This iteration Skips Loop
starting verification
start verif placeholder
end loop

starting verification# This iteration enters loop
start verif placeholder
in for loop #x91
in if loop
Still Starting 






end loop

admin: # loop Completes Services Restated
starting verification
start verif placeholder
in for loop #x80
Done
```

The case above show a correct outcome but sometimes the code will just run without completion.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Formatt your code and please be more specific

Comment: I would add an "else" with output you can see. It looks like it's not meeting either the if or the elif condition. Perhaps add an else: print 'match', match and print 'nomatch', nomatch to see what the results are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a "race condition" here: if you open the file *before* the service has started (or even begun starting), the file will be empty, so the `for` loop will end.  You have the right idea by sleeping, but you have to put this in a *second* loop, so you'll reopen the file and check it again.  Something like this:

```
def verify_serv():
    # Infinite loop to keep checking the file
    while True:
        # The `with` block ensures the file will be closed automatically
        with open('output2.txt') as f:
            for line in f:
                if '[STARTED]' in line:
                    # It's started, so we're done
                    return

        # But if we got here, it hasn't started yet, so sleep and try again
        time.sleep(5)
```